# Iterate URL's with Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to iterate over a list of URI's that I'm pulling from a CSV. I would appear that `requests` cannot use a variable in the URL string, but I wanted to check and see if anyone had any thoughts on how to make something like this work.

```
with open(fwinfo) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        try:
            rkey = requests.get('https://'row['ip_address'])
            if rkey.status_code == 200:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `SyntaxError`, which means you are getting your Python syntax wrong; this is not the fault of the `requests` library.

You need to use string concatenation or string formatting here; you cannot just place a variable after a string.

`+` concatenates strings:

```
rkey = requests.get('https://' + row['ip_address'])
```

or you can use `str.format()` to insert your CSV value into a string:

```
rkey = requests.get('https://{}'.format(row['ip_address']))
```

Take into account that HTTP servers often serve more than one website from a given IP address; different sites are served based on the `Host` header. Take that into account when using just IP addresses, you may have to manually add the host.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want here is:

```
rkey = requests.get('https://{}'.format(row['ip_address']))
```